# handle space character as input

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    char y;
    cin >> x;
    while(!cin)
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        cout << "Enter x and y again => ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cin >> x;
    }
    cin >> y;
    while (!(!isblank(y) && isalpha(y)))
    {
        cout << "You have entered wrong values try again!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter x and y again => ";
        cin >> x >> y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I try to handle if entered inputs are `1 a`. `x` should be a number `y` also should be alphabetic character. It should ask again to enter values `x` and `y`. However, It doesn't. It should accept `1a`. How can be the issue overcome?

Comment: it works for me.  if I enter `1a` `x` is `1` and `y` is `a`.  `operator >>` ignores all preceding white space for you.

Comment: what about with space character `1 a`? In this case, it should ask again to enter @NathanOliver

Comment: If spaces make a difference you should use getline() to read the entire line (instead of using cin)  and then parse the results yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would read one line at a time into a buffer and read from that buffer using `stringstream`. Here is what works for me:

```
int x;
char y;
bool readin_successful = false;
while (cin) {
    cout << "Please enter x and y => ";
    char z;
    string buffer;
    getline(cin, buffer);
    stringstream bin(buffer);
    bin >> x >> y;
    bool const first_ok = (isalpha(y) and bin.good());
    bin >> z;
    if (first_ok and not bin.good()) {
        readin_successful = true;
        break;
    }
    cout << "You have entered wrong values try again!" << endl;
}
cout << "Read: " << x << " " << y << " " << readin_successful << endl;
```

It accepts both `0 x` and `0x`, but not anything else (ignoring whitespace). [Here](http://ideone.com/tTG4WV) are the sample inputs I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

I've found its solution. [std::noskipws](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) means don't skip whitespaces.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    char y;
    cin >> x;
    while(!cin)
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        cout << "Enter x and y again => ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cin >> x;
    }
    cin >> noskipws >> y;
    while (!(!isblank(y) && isalpha(y)))
    {
        cout << "You have entered wrong values try again!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter x and y again => ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cin >> x >> y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```